# How to determine which commit and/or which branch was deployed to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have an app that is deployed to Heroku, and presume that I haven't done the deployment, how can I check which branch was used to deploy to heroku, or what is the commit ID (as with it I can determine the branch if needed)?

I am using GitHub.

So far I have tried to run in console:

```
$ heroku releases
```

and then running the:

```
$ heroku releases:info v123
```

But it didn't show anything.

How can I determine the commit or branch name from the deployed app on heroku?

It is a Rails app (maybe it might help to determine this information)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "releases" feature does not help you because it's an internal counter Heroku is using to keep track of pushes and re-configuration.

If you re-configure your app, the counter will increase. Deployments will also increase the counter but that doesn't help you.

But remember that Heroku is just another "git remote." So if you are on the machine which you used to deploy, there must be this:

```
$ git remote show heroku
* remote heroku
  Fetch URL: https://git.heroku.com/your-app-3367.git
  Push  URL: https://git.heroku.com/your-app-3367.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

If you have a similar output, you can just:

```
git show heroku/master
```

and see the commit that was pushed and deployed most recently.

Comment: I didn't have that information, as if I had, I would probably have the other information I have looked for. In any case, you have directed me to the correct answer. I have checked what was the app name, and I have cloned the heroku repo like this `git clone https://git.heroku.com/my-app-name.git` and I could check all the commits in my local (although it wasn't necessary for me to clone whole repository, I now have all that I need). P.S. Congratulations to the new privilege :)

Answer (score 7):

To see what's been deployed on the Heroku dashboard:  Just click the **Overview** tab. You'll see an Activity view on the right that shows recent deployments with commit hashes.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just go to Overview => latest activity  => Search for latest deployed item => Click compare diff on that item =>  Click on one commit => Check the branch there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `git log`
2. Use the 'd' key to scroll down until you spot "heroku/master"

#### Example

Here's an example. In this case, the commit on heroku is the *second most recent* commit i.e. 8f420b060317fa3c8763feba56381b51b391f392.

[image]

#### Another way

You can also use `git ls-remote` like so:

```sh
git ls-remote heroku
e437cb472232ec140fa6dd700e8b4a6b16b8b213    HEAD
e437cb472232ec140fa6dd700e8b4a6b16b8b213    refs/heads/main
8f420b060317fa3c8763feba56381b51b391f392    refs/heads/master
```

Since I know `git push heroku master` is used to push the master branch to the heroku remote, it can be inferred that `8f420b060317fa3c8763feba56381b51b391f392` is the latest commit on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that has not been mentioned is that you need to be on your main git branch to push your project to Heroku for the first time.

I was trying to push an existing project to Heroku and didnt see any information about switching branches.